# ReferenceError: goog is not defined

Tags: xtk

I am new on XTK with its things. 
I am following the X:DevelopersHeadsUp to try to run the demo html.

1) I clone the repository and run ./deps.py . Now the xtk-deps.js generated .
2) I invoke the html as given in the guide.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>XTK TEST WITHOUT COMPILATION</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../X/lib/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../X/xtk-deps.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  // include all used X-classes here
  // this is only required when using the xtk-deps.js file
  goog.require('X.renderer3D');
  goog.require('X.cube');

  var run = function() {

    var r = new X.renderer3D();
    r.container = 'r';
    r.init();

    var cube = new X.cube();

    r.add(cube);

    r.render();

  };
</script>

<body onload="run()">


  <div id="r" style="background-color: #000000; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

</body>
```

---

but failed with the error message ReferenceError: goog is not defined

Any thing wrong? 
thanks in advance .

MaiZi

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code, line 5.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../X/lib/closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../X/lib/google-closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
```

I updated the wiki on github:
[https://github.com/xtk/X/wiki/X:DevelopersHeadsUp](https://github.com/xtk/X/wiki/X%3aDevelopersHeadsUp)

Thank you